# Datetime operation in where clause of a SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query like

```
select *  
from tbltransaction 
where transactiondate < CAST('2014-10-30 22:09:59.570' AS DATETIME)
```

In this query the `transactiondate` should be less than `2014-10-30 00:00:00.000` is only displayed the transactiondate  like `2014-10-30 12:09:59.570`, `2014-10-30 20:09:59.570`, `2014-10-30 02:09:59.570` are not displayed. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

You Need to Use Same `DateType` on the both side of Filter Column like as below `DATETIME`

```
select * fom tbltransaction where 
CAST(transactiondate  as DATETIME) < 
CAST('2014-10-30 22:09:59.570' AS DATETIME)
```